# Would putting a thin layer of plexiglass over a UV-B fixture in a reptile enclosure filter out a significant amount of light?

Tags: reptiles, enclosure, lighting

I have a UV-A/UV-B fixture similar to the one below.  I would like to cover the bulb portion with plexiglass to protect it from moisture damage.

I'm afraid that covering it up will attenuate some of the crucial UV-B radiation for my reptile and render it useless in this regard.

To what extent (percentage, a ballpark estimate is more than ample) would putting a 1/8" piece of clear plexiglass over the bulb decrease the effectiveness of the lamp?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UV-B radiation is from about 280nm to 320nm (or 315nm depending on the reference that you use), and is subject to attenuation (and scattering) far more than the longer wavelength UV-A. As you more than likely know, there are different types of plexiglass.

The chart below compares the UV-Visible transmission properties of different types of plexiglass, taken from the blog entry [Infrared and Ultraviolet Transmission in Plexiglass Acrylic and Makrolon Polycarbonate Sheet](http://www.plasticgenius.com/2011/05/infrared-and-ultraviolet-transmission.html)  and the image is originally from [Plexiglas information sheet](http://www.ilphotonics.com/cdv2/Philips-%20Plastic%20Optics/raw%20material%20used.pdf) (Altuglas Group):

[image]

According to the blog, the curve labelled 'MC' is your general purpose plexiglass.  A key thing to note is the precipitous drop in transmittance (hence, increase in attenuation) in the high UV-A values.  The transmittance values in the UV-B area are extremely low, so much so that **even a thin piece of general purpose plexiglass would result in over 95% attenuation.**

The type labelled G [UVT (UV Transmitting)](http://www.polymerplastics.com/transparents_uvta.shtml) has impressive transmittance (low attenuation) in the UV-B, but this is a specialised product and is considerably more expensive than the standard.